# Should rental property purchased in January 2018 go on my 2018 tax return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, rental-property

Should I include this rental property purchase in my **2018** tax return?

The property was purchased in Jan. 2018. So should I be filing this property under my 2018 tax return (filed in 2019)? Basically, I should've purchased it before 2017 calendar year if I want to include in my 2017 tax return (the one I’m working on now in 2018 for last year)?

Comment: Why *shouldn't* you include rental property which *generated income and expenses* in your 2017 tax return?

Comment: My apologies. I mentioned the wrong year. See my corrections/edits above. Thanks!

Comment: Still confused.  Your tax return "*for this year (2018)*" will be filed **12 months from now**.

Comment: What do you mean "include this rental property purchase" on your tax return anyway? Rental income? expenses? something else? Also, tax questions require a country tag.

Comment: It is confusing indeed. I am filing my tax return for 2017 this year (2018).

Comment: @JohnFx: I mean should i declare/include the rental property in my 2017 tax return?

Comment: The terms you’ve used for naming the tax returns are confusing. Tax returns are named for the year that they cover, not the date that you file it. I’ve edited your question in an attempt to ask what I think it was you were trying to ask. Take a look and, if it doesn’t say what you want, edit your question further. In addition, take a look at JohnFx’s comment and talk about what specifically you are trying to include on your return.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar You don't claim property on your taxes, you claim revenue and expenses. I don't understand what you are asking. The fact that you owned a house would only apply to any state property taxes, not federal.

Comment: I think i was hoping that i would get some kind of tax credit/break for purchasing an investment property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 2018 tax return will be filed in 2019. We are currently in the 2017 tax season, we always file last years taxes at the start of the new year.

When you file your 2018 tax return (by mid-April 2019) you will include your rental property income (on Schedule E). Nothing to do with the rental property will go on your 2017 return.

Comment: And this is because i bought the rental property on January 2018, correct? Had i bought it in December 2017, then i would be including it in my 2017 tax return?

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar the IRS cares about *income and expenses*, not assets.  If you'd purchased it in Dec 2017, would you have received any income?  (You should have incurred expenses, which would reduce your AGI...)

Comment: Right, if you had purchased it in 2017 and placed it in service as a rental (not necessarily received any income from it) it would go on your 2017 return.